# Is there a term to describe a room only used to stop sound getting in?

Tags: terminology

an [acoustic anechoic chamber](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/33041/24455) has mainly 3 features

stopping sound getting in; 
stopping sound getting out;
reduce echoey.

Is there a term to describe a room only used to stop sound getting in?

Comment: I'm not aware of any material that allows sound to travel in a preferred orientation. Materials tend to transmit, attenuate, absorb or reflect sound uniformly. I'm unaware of a material or fabrication method that would allow sound out of a room but prevent it from entering a room. Surface textures (ripples & ridges) may preferentially reflect sound thus limiting the capacity to transmit sound.

Comment: Anechoic chamber works - you just define in which direction is the reason it is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acoustic test booth

> However, acoustic tests require special spaces. They should be conducted in a place where the sounds can be isolated and any unwanted noises are kept outside. This is where acoustic test booths come in.

https://www.enoisecontrol.com/acoustic-test-booth-chamber/

Specifically, a hemi-anechoic chamber has some sound-reflective inside surfaces, typically the floor, in order to simulate operating conditions.